# Which countries have blocked access to rt.com?

Tags: russian-federation, media, sanctions, freedom-of-speech

We know that the EU countries have blocked access to rt.com, and some people in India have also reported that they can no longer get to it. But not all western countries have blocked it. Does anyone have a list, or any more information, about where it is blocked and where it is not?

Comment: It's accessible from India.May be there is some difficulty in accessing the sites ( both Sputnik news and RT) . It's quite possible that the reason is they are checking the browsers for DDOS attacks. And sometimes both are not accessible because of slow connection  not from Indian side though.

Comment: I only think the ban is for others, within the EU, linking to rt.com. Eg. the app is gone in the app store and other private actors have removed links. I would assume the website itself is reachable from everywhere. At least it is from Denmark.

Comment: There's a DNS block (redirect) on RT.com in *some* EU countries. Changing your DNS server to 1.1.1.1 may help. In practice though, all their claims are reproduced by Indian and Chinese channels, and occasionally by Fox News pundits, so you're not missing much.

Comment: @Fizz - I may have missed some, but I don't think  any of the Indian media is reproducing the claims of any of the Russian news agencies. Most of the news are similar to CNN or BBC i.e. about the attacks and the destruction.So almost all the Indian media news about the war resembles  western media.And now the news are slowly dying also replaced by current election results in 5 States.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: Srsly? Try WION.

Comment: @Fizz- Ok , I don't know abt. WION , will take a look.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: I don't mean they're censored like the Russian channels, not showing any bombardments etc. But their commentary is very close to Russian positions. This unlike CGTN etc., which also censor any Western-style coverage.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1-uRaAbjUM for instance.

Comment: DId you search for it? Maybe there is information on Wikipedia about it?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: and before the war started they were like India-Russia BFF https://twitter.com/WIONews/status/1467501513752727553

Comment: @Fizz I can also see that many of the Indians discussing on YouTube are strongly supporting Russia. It seems that the history made strong solidarity of the Indian population for USSR and Russia.

Comment: @Fizz: I'm not seeing a DNS block. I can do nslookup rt.com from a machine in Portugal and see the correct result (185.178.208.5). But ping 185.178.208.5 doesn't get through.

Comment: I guess different countries implemented different measures. RT reported a DNS block in the Netherlands.

Comment: It's still accessible from the USA.

Answer (score 2):

Here an overview of what I quickly found on the subject in chronological order. I have divided this in 2 separate sections, where countries with bans are highlighted in the first section and corporate sanctions are highlighted in the 2nd section.

- 2014-08-01 - Ukraine banned RT.
- 2020-06-30 - Latvia banned 7 RT channels.
- 2022-07-07 - Lithuania banned RT from broadcasting.
- 2022-02-02 - Germany banned RT DE.
- 2022-02-24 - Poland banned RT from broadcasting.
- 2022-02-25 - Gibraltar suspended broadcast of RT.
- 2022-02-25 - Australia suspended RT new bulletins.
- 2022-02-26 - Australia removed the RT Channel was removed from broadcast.
- 2022-02-27 - EU Banned RT from broadcasting in the EU.

In addition to the above the following.

- 2022-02-25 - Alphabet (Google parent company) announced that RT is barred from receiving the proceeds of advertising.
- 2022-02-27 - Singapore, which received its feed from Europe, has consequently been forced to stop RT from broadcasting in Singapore due to lack of feed.
- 2022-02-28 - FaceBook, Instagram and TikTok made RT unavailable.
- 2022-02-28 - Microsoft removed RT from MSN.
- 2022-03-01 - Google banned access to RT.
- 2022-03-01 - Apple removed RT from its app store.
- 2022-03-01 - Roku dropped the RT app from its channel store.
- 2022-03-01 - DirectTV dropped RT from its channel lineup.
- 2022-03-01 - Sky New Zealand removed RT.
- 2022-03-03 - Reddit blocked new outgoing links to RT.
- 2022-03-11 - YouTube complete blocked RT worldwide.

The above is fluid though. If you have an update that I missed or came in after I wrote this article, you can let me know and I will include this in the above list.

Joey

Comment: Those are the TV channels, though. I was asking about the website rt.com .

Comment: In Czechia I can still access `rt.com` alhough the live stream seems to be nonfunctional (I have not checked the details). `rt.ru` seems to be blocked in Russia for me. I am getting response `The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.` signed by a valid TLS certificate for `rt.ru`. Also traceroute to `rt.ru` IP addresses continues through Sweden to Russian IP addresses.